# Adding dataclass fields dynamically with dacite.from_dict

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I am using *dacite* to transform a Python dictionary into a dataclass. Is there a way to dynamically add fields to a dataclass? Like in the example below, where the dataclass "Parameters" has defined only one timeseries "timeseriesA", but there might be additional ones (provided through the dictionary) that cannot be declared.

```
from dataclasses import asdict, dataclass
from typing import Dict, List, Optional

from dacite import from_dict

@dataclass(frozen = True)
class TimeSeries:
  name: str
  unit: str
  data: Optional[List[float]]
  
@dataclass(frozen = True)
class Parameters:
  timeseriesA: TimeSeries
  
@dataclass(frozen = True)
class Data:
  parameters: Parameters
  
  @classmethod
  def fromDict(cls, data: Dict) -> 'Data':
    return from_dict(cls, data)

  @classmethod
  def toDict(cls) -> Dict:
    return asdict(cls)

  
def main() -> None:

  d: Dict = {
    'parameters': {
      'timeseriesA': {
        'name': 'nameA',
        'unit': 'USD',
        'data': [10, 20, 30, 40]
      },
      'timeseriesB': {
        'name': 'nameB',
        'unit': 'EUR',
        'data': [60, 30, 40, 50]
      }
    }
  }

  data: Data = Data.fromDict(d)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

In this example, "timeseriesB" will be ignored by *dacite*, but should be added as field for the "Parameters" dataclass.

Comment: I feel like this is generally not good practice. If a field is not listed in the dataclass, how would you know to expect it? It's also a bad idea because most likely the IDE won't know such extra fields, and won't be able to assist in type hinting in these scenarios. Though I think you might be looking for something like a `dotdict` in this case - i.e. nested `dict` but with `.` access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, dynamically adding *fields* to a dataclass, after the class is defined, is not good practice. However, this does present a good use case for using a `dict` within a dataclass, due to the *dynamic* nature of fields in the source `dict` object.

Here is a straightforward example of using a `dict` field to handle a *dynamic* mapping of keys in the source object, using the [`dataclass-wizard`](https://dataclass-wizard.readthedocs.io/) which is also a similar JSON serialization library. The approach outlined below handles extraneous data in the dict object like `timeseriesB` for instance.

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from dataclasses import dataclass
from dataclass_wizard import JSONWizard


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Data(JSONWizard):
    parameters: dict[str, TimeSeries]


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class TimeSeries:
    name: str
    unit: str
    data: list[float] | None


data: dict = {
    'parameters': {
        'timeseriesA': {
            'name': 'nameA',
            'unit': 'USD',
            'data': [10, 20, 30, 40]
        },
        'timeseriesB': {
            'name': 'nameB',
            'unit': 'EUR',
            'data': [60, 30, 40, 50]
        }
    }
}


def main():
    # deserialize from dict
    d = Data.from_dict(data)
    print(d.parameters['timeseriesB'].unit)  # EUR

    print(repr(d)) 
    # Data(parameters={'timeseriesA': TimeSeries(name='nameA', unit='USD', data=[10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0]),
    #                  'timeseriesB': TimeSeries(name='nameB', unit='EUR', data=[60.0, 30.0, 40.0, 50.0])})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

The `dataclass-wizard` admittedly doesn't perform *strict* type checking like `dacite`, but instead performs *implicit* type coercion, like `str` to annotated `int`, where possible. Perhaps as a result, it's overall much faster; the other nice thing is serialization is even slightly faster than builtin `dataclasses.asdict` too :-)

Here are some quick tests:

```py
from dataclasses import asdict, dataclass
from typing import Dict, List, Optional

from dacite import from_dict
from dataclass_wizard import JSONWizard
from timeit import timeit


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class TimeSeries:
    name: str
    unit: str
    data: Optional[List[float]]


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Parameters:
    timeseriesA: TimeSeries


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Data:
    parameters: Parameters

    @classmethod
    def fromDict(cls, data: Dict) -> 'Data':
        return from_dict(cls, data)

    def toDict(self) -> Dict:
        return asdict(self)


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class ParametersWizard:
    # renamed because default key transform is `camelCase` -> `snake_case`
    timeseries_a: TimeSeries


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class DataWizard(JSONWizard):
    # enable debug mode in case of incorrect types etc.
    class _(JSONWizard.Meta):
        debug_enabled = True

    parameters: ParametersWizard


data: Dict = {
    'parameters': {
        'timeseriesA': {
            'name': 'nameA',
            'unit': 'USD',
            'data': [10, 20, 30, 40]
        },
        'timeseriesB': {
            'name': 'nameB',
            'unit': 'EUR',
            'data': [60, 30, 40, 50]
        }
    }
}


def main():
    n = 10_000

    print(f"From Dict:        {timeit('Data.fromDict(data)', globals=globals(), number=n):.3f}")
    print(f"From Dict (Wiz):  {timeit('DataWizard.from_dict(data)', globals=globals(), number=n):.3f}")

    data_1: Data = Data.fromDict(data)
    data_wiz: Data = DataWizard.from_dict(data)

    g = globals().copy()
    g.update(locals())

    print(f"To Dict:        {timeit('data_1.toDict()', globals=g, number=n):.3f}")
    print(f"To Dict (Wiz):  {timeit('data_wiz.to_dict()', globals=g, number=n):.3f}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Results, on my PC (Windows):

```
From Dict:        1.663
From Dict (Wiz):  0.059
To Dict:        0.105
To Dict (Wiz):  0.057
```